# Oracle Number Issue

Tags: sql, oracle

Good Day,

I have an issue I could use your help with.

A customer would like invoice amounts displayed as follows:

Example Invoice Amounts

```
-405.12 to be shown as 000000040512
```

&

```
-400.00 to be shown as 000000040000
```

The following query works fine for the 405.12 amount, but for the 400.00 amount it drops the two zeros on the right side

```
LPAD(REPLACE((invoiceamt*-1),'.',''),12,0)
```

How may I solve this issue?

Thank You
Aaron

Comment: multiply by -100 instead of replacing the . ?

Comment: Out of interest, how would an invoice amount of +400.00 be displayed?

Comment: The query only returns invoices that are in the negative, so +400.00 would not be returned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget the REPLACE, just multiply invoiceamt by -100 and then LPAD to the required length.

Comment: So simple yet so hard. Thank you, works like a charm.

Answer (score 7):

I suggest

```
 to_Char(abs(invoiceamt) * 100, '000000000000')
```

where

```
    abs  - absolute value - get rid of sign (-)
  * 100  - removing decimal point
to_Char  - final formatting (12 mandatory digits)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51367212/266304) has reminded me of the existence of [the `V` format model element](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#d56855e686):

> Returns a value multiplied by 10^*n* (and if necessary, round it up), where *n* is the number of 9's after the `V`.

But you can use zeros instead of 9s to keep leading zeros, and add `FM` to remove the leading space (which is there for a - symbol for negative values - which you won't have). So you can also do:

```
with t (n) as (
  select -405.12 from dual
  union all select -400 from dual
)
select n, to_char(abs(n), 'FM0000000000V00') as result
from t;

         N RESULT       
---------- -------------
   -405.12 000000040512 
      -400 000000040000
```