# Oracle To_Char function V in format string

Tags: sql, oracle, number-formatting, to-char

I was given Oracle code and I'm trying to figure out what it is doing. Specifically it's converting a number to a string and I don't understand it.

The code is:

```
TO_CHAR(QTY_DISPENSED,'0000000V000')
```

What does the V do?

Jeff

Answer (score 2):

It's a "Format Model" for converting numbers to strings: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm

> Returns a value multiplied by 10n (and if necessary, round it up), where n is the number of 9's after the V.

So basically it's taking your `QTY_DISPENSED` multiplying it by 1000 and returning a string.

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean in the above example the resulting string would be length of 7 characters?

Comment: In that same link you'll see that `0`  *Returns leading zeros.* so it should have at least 7 characters, and if less it will LPAD with 0's. *I believe